# My UIActionSheet acting like non-modal?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiactionsheet

```
NSLog(@"Display Action Sheet");

UIActionSheet *alert = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Proceed" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel (current data will be discard)" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert showInView:[self view]];
[alert release];

NSLog(@"Action Sheet Released");
```

This is my code that creates an action sheet. Before I see the action sheet, both "Display Action Sheet" and "Action Sheet Released" get output to the debugger console. Actually other codes that I want to execute AFTER I receive input from user are all executed before I am presented the action sheet.

This is rather weird. I thought I could use action sheet to execute codes based on user's input.

Comment: If you want a modal UIActionSheet check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244473/1204395

Answer (score 1):

Action sheets aren't modal. Pretty much nothing in iOS is. You need to handle whatever the user chooses in the sheet in one of the `UIActionSheetDelegate` methods, like `-actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:`.

Comment: I did implement actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex. To add more context, I have functions called a and b, and the action sheet is created in b. Inside a, after calling b, there are also function calls to, say, c and d. Now, the problem is c and d is executed before I see the action sheet. I now move c and d inside actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `UIActionSheetDelegate` in your header.

Answer (score 0):

If I want the answer to a question without the user allowing the option of cancel, I do something like this (key is : "if (buttonIndex == -1) performSelector")... Basically just loop till happy...

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (debug==1) {
        NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    if (buttonIndex == -1) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(selectDb) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    } else {
        [DataLayer selectDatabase: buttonIndex];
    }
}

- (void) selectDb {
    if (![DataLayer hasSelectedDatabase]) {
        actionSheet  = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filter" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Main", @"Training", @"Test 1", @"Test 2", @"Test 3", @"Test 4", nil];
         [actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
   }
}
```