# Returning result of button pressed on UIAlertView to C++ method

Tags: c++, objective-c, uialertview

I need to call a UIAlertView to be displayed from a C++ file. Depending on the button pressed, I need to return a bool to the C++ class itself (that bool in turn gets returned and is used elsewhere). I would like some advice on how to return the result to the C++ class. I have presumed that we can't set the C++ class as the delegate for the UIAlertView, so I need to somehow pass back which button is pressed to the C++ class.

This is the sample function call from C++ (it's a C++ class, but compiled as Objective-C:

```
bool CPlatform::WarningMessage(const wchar_t* message)
{
    // Some functions to convert message to an NSString* wNSString

    MessagePopUp *message = [[MessagePopUp alloc] init];
    [message showPopUpWithMessage:wNSString];

    // This function should return true if OK is pressed, or False if Cancel is pressed.
}
```

Then, I have a simple class to display the alert

```
@interface MessagePopUp : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
BOOL OKPressed;
}

- (void) showPopUpWithMessage:(NSString*)message;

@end

@implementation MessagePopUp

- (void) showPopUpWithMessage:(NSString*)message
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"ok");
        OKPressed = true;

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"cancel");
        OKPressed = false;
    }
}

@end
```

Can you recommend a way that I can return the result / OKPressed to the C++ function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this easily as thinking about the code flow will tell you.

The problem is the run loop and that [UIAlertView is non blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753154/make-uialertview-blocking) to display the alertView (i.e. after calling `[alert show]`) you need to return control to iOS which means that your C++ function `bool CPlatform::WarningMessage(const wchar_t* message)` must return before you know which button has been pressed.

You could try and build [a blocking UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573773/truly-modal-uialertview-in-iphone) but it's not a good idea even though this type of thing [is possible](http://najimmy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Paint4HB/Classes/ModalHUD.m).

A better idea would be to go with the flow and define a callback in your C++ `CPlatform` class which accepts the `OKPressed` bool you have in your `clickedButtonAtIndex` delegate method.

Comment: Thanks Roger. I agree that it's probably not best to try and build a blocking UIAlertView. I was trying to not make too many amends to the CPlatform class (outside of that particular function call), but I'll try and cobble up a callback like you suggest.

Comment: anyone has an idea of how to define the callback in C++?

Answer (score -2):

If you can mix the two languages, then you could use an objective-c concept called the NSNotificationCenter.

This code adds a listener to the parent of the "show the alert" class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(MethodYouWantToUseWhenClicked) 
                                             name:@"alertViewClicked" 
                                           object:showAlertClass];
```

Then in the alert view class you could do the following to send the message:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // Not sure, but I think buttonIndex == 0 is actually cancel.
        NSLog(@"cancel");
        self.OKPressed = false;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"alertViewClicked" 
                                                            object:self];
    } else {

        self.OKPressed = false;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"alertViewClicked" 
                                                            object:self];
    }
}
```

Then you simply have to access the boolean property from your parent class/C++.

Comment: This doesn't solve the a synchronicity/blocking problem that @payino is asking for help with. It's just another way of asynchronously delivering the results.